# Assert an Individual - Class relation in Protégé

Tags: protege

I wish to assert a relationship between an individual and a class. E.g I have "John" in class "Smith", and I would like to have the assertion "Works_In" to class "Tesco" so it would read "John" WorksIn "Tesco" within protégé.

I tried using the object property assertions but that only lets me do individual to individual assertions, and when I use the data property assertions, the reasoner doesn't work with it.

Comment: You seem to be thinking in terms of object-orientation wrt ontologies. I have written about how to approach this on my blog [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/mathematical-formalization-of-object-orientation/).

Comment: If in your ontology Tesco is a class, it would represent all of the Tesco supermarkets. But John can work only at one Tesco supermarket. If instead John works for the Tesco company that owns the supermarkets, then there should be an individual of type Company ("Tesco PLC") and then Jon works_in Tesco PLC. (I'm guessing here at what could be the rest of your ontology)